# debian buster exim4 hostname --fqdn did not return a fully qualified name

Tags: debian, exim

I'm running debian buster, and let exim4 deliver for localhost mail from apt-listchanges. this works but I get the error

```
alex@Taomon:~$ LANG=C
alex@Taomon:~$ systemctl status exim4
* exim4.service - LSB: exim Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/exim4; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-11-29 10:51:40 CET; 5h 36min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1299 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/exim4 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4340)
   Memory: 5.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/exim4.service
           `-1571 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m

Nov 29 10:51:40 Taomon systemd[1]: Starting LSB: exim Mail Transport Agent...
Nov 29 10:51:40 Taomon exim4[1299]: Starting MTA:hostname --fqdn did not return a fully qualified name, dc_minimaldns will not
Nov 29 10:51:40 Taomon exim4[1299]: work. Please fix your /etc/hosts setup.
Nov 29 10:51:40 Taomon exim4[1299]:  exim4.
Nov 29 10:51:40 Taomon systemd[1]: Started LSB: exim Mail Transport Agent.
alex@Taomon:~$
```

I read over the years some sides but never understood to solve it. I tried more than once

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

some I hope relevant infos

```
alex@Taomon:~$ cat /etc/hostname 
Taomon
alex@Taomon:~$
```

```
    root@Taomon:~# hostnamectl status
       Static hostname: Taomon
             Icon name: computer-laptop
               Chassis: laptop
            Machine ID: 84876d350fa0dd8b520fd47e0000000b
               Boot ID: 0144c780c7d747de92e1fbb41b1b506e
      Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
                Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-18-amd64
          Architecture: x86-64
    root@Taomon:~#
```

Next to long for here
[Exim in address testing mode](https://paste.ubuntuusers.de/424085/)

Note exim delivers my mail correct. But the error makes me nervous.
Almost forgot

```
root@Taomon:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Taomon

#PS4 einbinden

#172.16.0.2      PS4

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#fe00::0 ip6-localnet
#ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
root@Taomon:~#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace the line

```
127.0.1.1   Taomon
```

in `/etc/hosts` with

```
127.0.1.1  taomon.example.com taomon
```

from manpage

> The recommended method of setting the FQDN is to make the hostname be
> an alias for the fully qualified name using /etc/hosts, DNS, or NIS.
> For  example, if the hostname was "ursula", one might have a line in
> /etc/hosts which reads
>
> ```
>           127.0.1.1    ursula.example.com ursula
> ```

Comment: sorry, but I get after restarting exim4.service the same error. Or do I have to reboot the system?

Comment: @nobody Reboot should not be necessary but has the advantage that you know whether it works after a reboot. You have to set the short hostname with the `hostname` command in that case. And some caching services may prevent the new FQDN from being recognized.

Comment: not emough coffee today? It have to be the other whay around. On debian buster `127.0.1.1 taomon.example.com taomon`  No warnings now. and `hostname --fqdn
taomon.example.com`